# Cannot open include file: 'libgen.h'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, include

I want to use `basename` function. So include like this:

```
#include <libgen.h>
char *dirname(char *path);
char *basename(char *path);
```

But **Visual Studio** show me error like this :

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libgen.h': No such file or directory
IntelliSense: cannot open source file "libgen.h"
```

Is `libgen.h` not a reference header file? Why I can't include?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find it in the file system?

Comment: try to locate it in the file system. if you could find it go to visual properties and set the path to it.

Comment: Thanks! I will try. But How can find header in file system? I try to file search but I can't found... T-T

Comment: Visual Studio does neither have this header nor these functions. If using [`_splitpath_s, _wsplitpath_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx) isn't an option, then you have to write them by yourself.